# How to notify user to scroll down the tableview

Tags: ios, iphone, user-interface, hig

[image: ScrollToView]

I have a tableview(highlighted in red rectangle) that will show only 3 rows at a time, now if i have the rows more than three, then i want to notify user to scroll down the tableview to view the rest of row.

In windows we will have a physical scroll bar on the right side, but in iPhone, showing scroll bar all the time is not possible.

Can any one tell me what is the best way to notify the user to scroll when we have more row to size.

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: in general that is very poor choice of collecting inputs from the user. it would be more practical to open a new view with the possible elements and the user could choose any of them, then the list of the elements can be removed from the navigation stack. in practice for good references of how to build a proper user interface, open the **iOS Settings** or **iOS Calendar** applications for further experience, and read the _HIG_ and _Transition Guide_ for collecting backgrounds. the regular iOS user demands that behaviour from an iOS app, rather than any custom solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to make the height not a multiple of the row height.

if `rowheight = 44;` then `tableheight = 110;` or `tableheight = 154;` , this will show if there is a visible half row, which will lead the user to scroll.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you should not worry about notifying this to user. Any iOS user will understand that they can scroll it. Still if you want you can use:

```
scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES.
```

Also you can see:
http://www.developers-life.com/scrollview-with-scrolls-indicators-which-are-shown-all-the-time.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend this kind of UX for an iOS app. You should remember that the recommended area of touch are 40*40px. However, a common practise (you can see it on the App Store app) it's to make the `UITableView` big enough so it can hold 3 and half cells, so the user get the hint there is more.

Answer (score 0):

Add your table on UIScrollView then you can show vertical indicator of scroll view.

yourScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES.

Answer (score 0):

You can make scroll indicators visible

```
tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
```

Or "flash" them

```
[tableView flashScrollIndicators];
```